# Issue with using Nuxt + @nuxtjs/svg and dynamic import of SVGs

Tags: svg, nuxt.js

I'm currently using the NuxtJS/svg package and having problems with dynamic import.

For example:

- I have 10 SVGs inside /assets/images
- I have an index.vue page

**Case 1)**

I include 1 SVG as raw on the page like this:

```
<span v-html="require(`../assets/images/one.svg?raw`)" />
```

Result: Everything is fine. Nuxt creates a JS chunk file that includes the one.svg.

**Case 2)**

The problem case. I include the same SVG as raw but via dynamic import:

```
<span v-html="require(`../assets/images/${imageName}.svg?raw`)" />
```

*imageName* is declared in data and has the value "one".

Result: Nuxt creates a JS chunk file that includes the one.svg ***as well as all other 9 SVGs!***

Why are images, that are not referenced anywhere, included in my JS chunks? I fell into that problem in a big project and have now recreated it with a sample app. Any ideas?

Comment: Probably because when you do something dynamic, webpack has no idea how to know if you need to import a specific image or not. Hence it is importing all.

Comment: Yes but there has to be a solution/workaround for that?! :-/

Comment: I have read about how webpack handles dynamic import.  I'll use another way to use my icons.